# How to get F# syntax highlighting?

Tags: miktex, pandoc, syntax-highlighting

I'm using MiKTeX via pandoc to make a book that contains C# and F# source code. The C# source code gets formatted just fine. How do I make sure the F# code gets formatted also?

Comment: What utility are you using to format C# source?

Comment: Python library `pygments` do has a [lexer for F#](https://pygments.org/docs/lexers/#pygments.lexers.dotnet.FSharpLexer), so you can use `mitned` to highlight/format.

Answer (score 4):

Pandoc uses the [syntax definitions](https://kate-editor.org/syntax/) from KDE's Kate editor. F# is included in that list. In fact, if you run `pandoc --list-highlight-languages`, you'll find `cs` (for C#) and `fsharp` (for F#). Not sure how that inconsitency came to be.

So it should be sufficient to start your code blocks with ```` ``` fsharp ```` to get proper highlighting. You may have to update pandoc to make sure fsharp support is included.

If you'd rather use *minted* than pandoc's built-in highlighter, checkout the [`minted` pandoc Lua filter](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/minted).

Comment: I am using the ```` fsharp` code you mention but it is 100%, definitely, NOT working.

Comment: Does `pandoc --list-highlight-languages | grep fsharp` give any output? If not, update pandoc. If it does, please raise the issue in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/new).

Comment: turns out there is a bug; question updated

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this problem is the result of a bug/omission. For C#, you can use either `c#` or `csharp` as the language identifier. For F#, you can use `fsharp` but NOT `f#`, the latter simply does not work. Changing everything to `fsharp` fixed the issue.